# Unable to use grease pencil in BLENDER version 3.3.1

Tags: animation

I am new to Blender. I downloaded version 3.3.1. When I go 2D animation, add grease pencil, and try to draw, I can't see what I'm drawing. I cannot use the icons on the left (eraser, etc.). message: *Draw  needs strokes in the active grease pencil object*.

I may be using the wrong version or I may have forgotten to activate something.
What would be the best version to draw in 2D and make an animation?

Comment: Bienvenu! Malheureusement, pour l'instant, nous ne pouvons accepter les questions qu'en anglais. Utilisez peut-être Google Translate pour votre question et ses réponses.